# UNREAL: How do you store players progress on local device

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Firstly I completely understand this will be fully documented somewhere, I just have no idea where to start due to being a beginner so please have a bit of mercy lol.

I just need to permanently store two pieces of data;

**1:** The amount of in game currency the player has collected

**2:** How many levels have been completed by the player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a peak at the unreal engine docs. They should definitely be the first place to take your questions. Look at the FFileHelper module in the docs here https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Misc/FFileHelper/. I believe that SaveArrayToFile() or another simmilar function would work for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SaveGame](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/SaveGame/) system, it is designed to abstract away the underlying platform's file system, and you can work directly with `UPROPERTY`s and don't have to write your own serialization and deserialization code.